# Does Sql Server 2000 support SSIS transactions?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, ssis

I am running an SSIS package, that pulls data from two SQL Servers, One is a SQL Server 2008 and the other is a SQL Server 2000. I have been trying to implement transactions in SSIS lately.

The problem i am facing now is, the package always fail reading the SQL Server 2000 when transaction level in the packages is set to required, with an Error `The Acquire Connection manager failed with error code 0xC0202009`

Tried:

1. Checking if the DTC service is started in both machine, the client and the Database Server and they are both started.
2. On the Client, went to **Control Panel** >> **Component Services** >> **Computers** >> **My Computer** >> **Distributed Transaction Coordinator** >> **Local DTS** (Right Click, then Chooose Properties ) >> **Security Tab** 
   ( Allow Remote Clients, Allow Inbound, Allow Outbound ) are all selected
3. On the **2000 SQL Server**,went to **Control Panel** >> **Component Services** >> **Computers** >> **My Computer** >> **Distributed Transaction Coordinator** >> (No Local DTS) and right clicking will not give me properties of the DTC, cant find a way to access the options ( Allow Remote Clients, Allow Inbound, Allow Outbound )

Now I was wondering does SQL Server 2000 support SSIS transactions?

Comment: before editing you used several question marks where only one was need e.g. `Does Sql Server 2000 support SSIS transactions?????`

Comment: Could you elaborate on "On the 2000 SQL Server, there is no way to access the above components"? I've certainly had to make DTC changes for SQL Server 2000 before...

Comment: Made changes to the question, as requested

Answer (score 5):

[`SSIS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) was first released with SQL Server 2005 - so it is *not* supported on SQL Server 2000.

Look at [`DTS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transformation_Services) which was what `SSIS` replaced.

---

Use [`DTCPing`](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2868) to ensure that distributed transactions are setup correctly on both servers.

Comment: Yeah, even though SSIS was released with SQL Server 2005, but you can still create OLE DB Source Controls that get data from a 2000 SQL Server, and this will work fine. But wen you implement transactions, the package fails to Acquire connection

Comment: @Brian Paul - Have you run DTCPing on both machines?

Comment: But an SSIS package (running on a 2005 or 2008 server) should be able to connect to a 2000 database, use one as a source or destination, etc, so far as I'm aware, which I think is what the OP is doing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Yes, which is why I want the OP to confirm if distributed transactions are correctly setup on both servers.

Comment: Downloaded the DTCPing.exe, tried pinging both the **SQL Server 2000** and the **SQL Server 2008** and they are both failing  giving RPC test failed,

Comment: @Brian - Then there is no chance that transactions will work. Read the documentation for DTCPing and change your MSDTC configuration on both servers till it works (hint: the configuration must match on both).

Answer (score 0):

For:

> On the **2000 SQL Server**,went to **Control Panel** >> **Component Services** >> **Computers** >> **My Computer** >> **Distributed Transaction Coordinator** >> (No Local DTS) and right clicking will not give me properties of the DTC, cant find a way to access the options ( Allow Remote Clients, Allow Inbound, Allow Outbound )

Stop before that point. Right click on **My Computer** (inside component services, etc), and choose Properties. There is an MSDTC tab. Inside there, you can open "Security Configuration...", and in there you'll find the Remote Clients, Inbound, Outbound, etc.